# There is a delete line when I want to define channelconfig for audiotrack

Tags: java, android, audiotrack

[Delet line exists when I define a channel type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Q3xq.png)

Comment: It means that member is deprecated. In most cases javadoc explains what should be used instead.

Answer (score 0):

It means that you are trying to use a deprecated constant.

Javadoc says:

> This constant was deprecated in API level 5. Use CHANNEL_OUT_MONO or CHANNEL_IN_MONO instead.